# How to create a simple redirect with JSF?

Tags: jsf

How do I create a simple redirect with jsf?

I tried:

```
    <h:form>
        <h:commandButton action="www.google.de" value="go to google" />
    </h:form>
```

But when I click the button, I just stay on the index page. Nothing happens!
What is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is JSF absolutely necessary here? You don't seem to need to submit anything to your side at all. Just use plain HTML.

```
<form action="http://www.google.de">
    <input type="submit" value="Go to Google" />
</form>
```

Please note that the URL to the external site must include the scheme (the `http://` part), otherwise it would just be submitted relative to the current request URI, such as `http://example.com/context/www.google.de`.

If you really need to submit to your side, e.g. to preprocess and/or log something, then you could use `ExternalContext#redirect()` in the action method.

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton value="Go to Google" action="#{bean.submit}" />
</h:form>
```

with

```
public void submit() throws IOException {
    // ...

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("http://www.google.de");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
<h:commandButton value="Go to Google" type="button" onclick="window.location.href = 'http://www.google.de';" />
```

No need for a form.